# Send Sharing Link for Sharepoint Folder

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have been battling with this for a few days now... I am using CSCOM to connect to SharePoint.  Everything is working fine, creating folders and uploading files.  However, I now need to create a shared folder (parent level) link for external users and then initiate the email invite as per the "links giving access" not direct access.  I can create and send an anonymous link but this is not what we are after.

```
string s = "password";
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in s)
                passWord.AppendChar(c);

            string siteURL = "siteurl";
            string parentFolder = "parentfolder";


            using (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext CContext = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext(siteURL))
            {
                CContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("s-eConnect@nzblood.co.nz",passWord);
                var subFolders = CContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(parentFolder).Folders;
                CContext.Load(subFolders);
                CContext.ExecuteQuery();

                <<create sharing link for parent folder and send email to external user>>>

                foreach (var subFolder in subFolders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(subFolder.Name.ToString());
                    
                }

            }
```

The above code iterates thru the sub folders of the parent, this is me just making sure I am getting the right data.  But I can't seem to find anything that allows me to create the sharing link and send to an external user so they get an invite etc...

If I add in the following, it creates an invite but adds the user to the entire site via Direct Access ... not by link to the folder....

```
var users = new List<UserRoleAssignment>();
                users.Add(new UserRoleAssignment()
                {
                    UserId = "rhyndman@altara.net",
                    Role = Role.View
                });

                WebSharingManager.UpdateWebSharingInformation(CContext, CContext.Web, users, true, "You've been invited...", true, true);
                CContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `DocumentSharingManager.UpdateDocumentSharingInfo` method to send Sharing Link for Sharepoint Folder: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt143107(v=office.15)

```
 DocumentSharingManager.UpdateDocumentSharingInfo(CContext, folderabsoluteUrl, users, true, true, true, "You've been invited...", true, true);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, this works but only to give the user direct access, it doesn't create the external user in the "links giving access" section. The business is not happy with this approach :(